# What is err:504 in phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Anybody knows what is the error Err:504 in phpexcel? I am getting this error on the excel cell with formula

`=INDEX($'Country Data (D)'.F1:F25;MATCH($G$7&$G$8;$'Country Data (D)'.A1:A25&$'Country Data (D)'.B1:B25;0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP Error 504 Gateway timeout 
http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E504.html